# Custom snapshot serialiser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm literally trying 1:1 the test that is in Jest docs for customising the snapshot serialiser: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#snapshotserializers-arraystring

```
module.exports = {
  serialize(val, config, indentation, depth, refs, printer) {
    return `Pretty foo: ${printer(val.foo)}`;
  },

  test(val) {
    return val && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(val, 'foo');
  },
};


test(() => {
  const bar = {
    foo: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
    },
  };

  expect(bar).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')` (Jest 29.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"jest": "^29.7.0"`. It seems like a bug. Take a look this implementation [/jest-snapshot/src/mockSerializer.ts#L25](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/4e56991693da7cd4c3730dc3579a1dd1403ee630/packages/jest-snapshot/src/mockSerializer.ts#L25)

And [`printer`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/4e56991693da7cd4c3730dc3579a1dd1403ee630/packages/pretty-format/src/index.ts#L358) function source code:

```js
function findPlugin(plugins: Plugins, val: unknown) {
  for (let p = 0; p < plugins.length; p++) {
    try {
      if (plugins[p].test(val)) {
        return plugins[p];
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new PrettyFormatPluginError(error.message, error.stack);
    }
  }

  return null;
}

// ...
function printer(
  val: unknown,
  config: Config,
  indentation: string,
  depth: number,
  refs: Refs,
  hasCalledToJSON?: boolean,
): string {
  const plugin = findPlugin(config.plugins, val);
  if (plugin !== null) {
    return printPlugin(plugin, val, config, indentation, depth, refs);
  }

  const basicResult = printBasicValue(
    val,
    config.printFunctionName,
    config.escapeRegex,
    config.escapeString,
  );
  if (basicResult !== null) {
    return basicResult;
  }

  return printComplexValue(
    val,
    config,
    indentation,
    depth,
    refs,
    hasCalledToJSON,
  );
}
```

The error happens at `findPlugin(config.plugins, val)`, the `config` is `undefined`.

You should pass the other parameters of the `serialize` function to the `printer` function.

Try

`custom-serializer.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  serialize(val, config, indentation, depth, refs, printer) {
    return `Pretty foo: ${printer(val.foo, config, indentation, depth, refs)}`;
  },

  test(val) {
    return val && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(val, 'foo');
  },
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const custom = require('./custom-serializer');

expect.addSnapshotSerializer(custom);

test('77645932', () => {
  const bar = {
    foo: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
    },
  };

  expect(bar).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
Pretty foo: {
  "x": 1,
  "y": 2,
}
`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I really could have taken a look by myself at the source code :) thanks for saving me some time.